# How to assert or validate the sorting order of a response json data on SoapUI

Tags: soapui

For a get request im getting a json response and it contain some school data.The schools should be appear by descending order for the school rating number.

Somthing looks like this.

> {
>            "location": "Sydney",
>            "minStudentAge": 18,
>            "schoolType": "Business",
>            "rating": 5,
>
> ```
>   },
>         {
>      "location": "Sydney",
>      "minStudentAge": 13,
>      "schoolType": "Business",
>      "rating": 5,
>
>   },
>         {
>      "location": "Sydney",
>      "minStudentAge": 16,
>      "schoolType": "Business",
>      "rating": 3,
>
>   },
>         {
>      "location": "Sydney",
>      "minStudentAge": 18,
>      "schoolType": "Business",
>      "rating": 1,
>
>   },
>         {
>      "location": "Sydney",
>      "minStudentAge": 16,
>      "schoolType": "Business",
>      "rating": 2,             }
>       ]
> ```

So every node is having a value named "Rating" and i need to validate whether the return json contains data on correct order. Rating top (5) should be at the top of the list and rating low (1) should be at the bottom of the list.